# C# парсинг сложных сайтов

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, парсер

Привет!
Как можно распарсить сайт, у которого html-код не содержит нужных данных в явном виде?
Например, нужно с этой страницы https://ekb.zarplata.ru/vacancy?rubric_id[]=171 дернуть все вакансии с их описаниями и прочей информацией.
Если кликнуть по вакансии, то открывается ее полное описание.
Но если посмотреть код страницы, то там невозможно найти дату вакансии, адрес работодателя, полные описания со всеми полями. Что-то есть конечно, но не все и не в таком виде.
Да и вообще из исходного кода невозможно получить информацию о количестве страниц с вакансиями, а значит, невозможно и узнать количество вакансий.

Как решаются такие задачи? Я совсем новичок в парсинге, пока дошел только до разбора html кода регулярками. Но даже если использовать спец библиотеки типа Angle Sharp, то как получить то, чего нет в коде страницы?

В интернете ничего толком не нашел. Буду признателен за любые советы, где чего можно почитать-посмотреть. Хочу понять сам принцип парсинга таких страниц.

Comment: такие страницы парсить ещё проще - там информация уже структурирована. Откройте в браузере вкладку developer tools -> network и научитесь ею пользоваться. Ну или wireshark.

Comment: При клике происходит "догрузка" данных AJAX запросов. По этому вы их и не видите. Данные при этом поступают в Json формате - посмотрите какой запрос генерируется и повторите его.

Answer (score 1):

Есть 2 пути. Правильный и неправильный, но проще для понимания "новичками".

Неправильный будет использовать веб-драйвер и доставать код через него :) Ищешь информацию о Selenium Web-Driver и пробуешь имитировать действия пользователя. Потом достаешь хтмл страницы после всех нужных действий. Уверен, он вернет полный.

Павильным будет подсмотреть пост/гет запросы и генеря их доставать нужные данные и парсить Json вместо хтмл, как сказал Воробьев Александр.